# x86 logical address syntax error

Tags: c++, x86, inline-assembly

Compiler: `gcc 4.7.1, 32bit, ubuntu`

Here's an example:

```
    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int mem = 0;

        __asm volatile
        (
            "mov ebx, esp\n\t"
            "mov %0, [ds : ebx]\n\t"
            : "=m"(mem)
        );

        printf("mem = 0x%08x\n", mem);

        return 0;
    }

gcc -masm=intel -o app main.c
```

Assembler messages: `invalid use of register!`

As I know, ds and ss point to the same segment. I don't know why I can't use [ds : ebx] logical address for addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

**One**: the indirect memory reference should be:

```
mov %0, ds : [ebx]
```

That is, with the `ds` out of the brackets.

**Two**: A single instruction cannot have both origin and destination in memory, you have to use a register. The easiest way would be to indicate `=g` that basically means *whatever*, but in your case it is not possible because `esp` cannot be moved directly to memory. You have to use `=r`.

**Three**: (?) You are clobbering the `ebx` register, so you should declare it as such, or else do not use it that way. That will not prevent compilation, but will make your code to behave erratically.

In short:

```
  unsigned int mem = 0;
  __asm volatile
  (
    "mov ebx, esp\n\t"
    "mov %0, ds : [ebx]\n\t"
    : "=r"(mem) :: "ebx"
  );
```

Or better not to force to use `ebx`, let instead the compiler decide:

```
  unsigned int mem = 0, temp;
  __asm volatile
  (
    "mov %1, esp\n\t"
    "mov %0, ds : [%1]\n\t"
    : "=r"(mem) : "r"(temp)
  );
```

BTW, you don't need the `volatile` keyword in this code. That is used to avoid the assembler to be optimized away even if the output is not needed. If you write the code for the side-effect, add `volatile`, but if you write the code to get an output, do not add `volatile`. That way, if the optimizing compiler determines that the output is not needed, it will remove the whole block.

Comment: The `volatile` keyword also prevents the compiler from moving or reordering the assembly code with respect to other code (e.g. hoisting it out of a loop).

Comment: *That is not possible because it is a local variable, and as such does not have a fixed address* - `"m"` / `"=m"` constraints work with any rvalue / lvalue, respectively.  If the compiler knows how to write to it, it can generate an addressing mode to access it.  The addressing mode it fills in doesn't have to be absolute or RIP-relative; it can be something like `[4 + rsp]` like for this case. (example: https://godbolt.org/z/o8z5qEjo9)  The code in the question has many problems, but that's not one of them.  It's pointlessly inefficient to force a memory instead of register operand, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are totally right, I kind of fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't the only error.  You can `mov [esp+8], esp` if you want; there's no reason you couldn't use an `"=g"(stack_pointer)` output. In AT&T syntax, `asm ("mov %%esp, %0" : "=g"(stack_pointer));`, or with -masm=intel `asm ("mov %0, esp" : "=g"(stack_pointer));`

Comment: Oh, but this code wants to load from `[esp]`, not moving `esp`.  You're right you can't do that, but you mis-described it as moving ESP.  So yeah, `asm( "mov %0, ds:[esp]", "=r"(top_of_stack) );`.  (Or under a mainstream OS, just `[esp]` and let it use SS.)  It's pointless to copy ESP to another register, and GCC doesn't know how to generate code for a memory model where SS and DS bases aren't equal.  It always assumes a flat memory model.  (Also, giving the compiler a free choice could let it pick EBP, which would also imply SS.)

Comment: Of course, this whole inline asm seems totally flaky; there's no guarantee what ESP will be pointing at when this instruction executes.  If you want the return address, use `__builtin_return_address(0)`.